# error: failed to solve: snapshot does not exist: not found

Tags: docker, buildx

When running

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7 -t my-project .
```

it fails with a *very* cryptic error message:

```
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error: failed to solve: snapshot  does not exist: not found
```

which I can't find in google.

This is on debian, I just switched from debian's `docker.io` for the `docker-ce` package to get buildx support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cryptic error is shown when using `docker buildx` with a buildx-capable `docker` command, but with the docker service still being the old non-buildx-capable one.

Manually restart the docker service with

```
service docker restart
```

(or similar, depending on your service system) and buildx will work just fine.